# Prove that $\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \sqrt{a_n}\frac{1}{n^s}$ converges for $s>\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume that $a_n \ge 0$ for $n=0,1.....$ and $,\sum  a_n< \infty$  prove that $$\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \sqrt{a_n}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ converges for $s>\frac{1}{2}$

***my idea***

$|\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \sqrt{a_n}\frac{1}{n^s}|^2 \leq (\sum _{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n})^2(\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \frac{1}{n^s})^2$

I am trying solve this way but not get the answer..please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz:
\begin{align*}
\sum\sqrt{a_{n}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^{s}}\leq\left(\sum a_{n}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2s}}\right)^{1/2}<\infty,
\end{align*}
since $2s>1$.